# Cannot read property of undefined at Object.eval angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to obtain data from a combobox and print data in a textbox, for example according to the user id, print the name of the user in the textbox by selecting its id from the combobox, I hope you understand and that it is well written, my English not very good

i try this ...

html component

```
  <mat-select  [(ngModel)]="examen.rutPac" name="rutPac">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let pacientes of pacientes" name="rutPac" [value]="pacientes.rutPac">
      {{pacientes.rutPac}}
    </mat-option>

            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectedPaciente.nombrePac" #elementDescripcionControl="ngModel"
        type="text" name="NombrePac" placeholder="Nombre Paciente" maxlength="30" readonly>
```

component ts

```
  getOnePaciente = (pac) => {
    this.dataService.getOnePaciente(pac.id).subscribe(
      (data: Paciente) => {
        this.selectedPaciente = data; 
        console.log('JSON DATA --->', data); 
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  getPacientes(): void {
    this.dataService
      .getPacientes()
      .then(pacientes => this.pacientes = pacientes);
  }

"the model"
   pacientes:Paciente[];
```

[image: this is the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `?` to make the undefined variable optional this is known as point out by **@Mostafa** as '*safe navigation*' :

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedPaciente?.nombrePac"
```

**Like:**

```
 <input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectedPaciente?.nombrePac" #elementDescripcionControl="ngModel"
        type="text" name="NombrePac" placeholder="Nombre Paciente" maxlength="30" readonly>
```

The `?` may help avoiding the error while the `selectedPaciente` is unassigned

or an `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedPaciente">
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectedPaciente.nombrePac" #elementDescripcionControl="ngModel"
        type="text" name="NombrePac" placeholder="Nombre Paciente" maxlength="30" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: this ?
Do I have to use it in the html or in the ts? , can you show me an example please, thanks for the comment

Comment: @DiegoMoreno I just added the demo

Answer (score 1):

make sure to import FormsModule in your app module at first.
and then you may use 'safe navigation operator (?)' and null property path to make undefined vars optional.

Comment: If you agree with a response it might be better if you give it a vote up instead of duplicating it. Unless of course you believe you could add more value(information) than the original response

Comment: @Dalorzo Thank you for reminding me stackoverflow protocols.I wasn't aware that you gave the same answer at first.